# Pandas Filling Missing Rows Based on Defined List

Tags: python, pandas, data-transform

`Original` DF has values that are calculated from a table.

It may have `type` missing for few ids.
However, the goal is explicitly list if the flag `exists`.
If not, `type` row should be added with `no` in the `exists` column.

id=1 is good in this example. If I filter on id=2 only, and run the following code, it returns c. which I can then `append`.

```
aa = set(type)
bb = set(b['type'].to_list())
list(aa - bb)
```

However, as you can tell, this is not feasible when applying to all id.

I needed help so the code can be applied for all the ids.

This returns the type that are no

```
type = [a, b, c]

Original
id      type    flag    
1       a       y        
1       b       y
1       c       y
2       a       y      
2       b       y
3       b       y     

Goal
id      type    flag    exists 
1       a       y       yes        
1       b       y       yes       
1       c       y       yes       
2       a       y       yes            
2       b       y       yes   
2       c       y       no     
3       a       y       yes        
3       b       y       no 
3       b       y       no
```

Hoping there is a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to generate a Cartesian product between set of ids and set of types.  I've used this [Cartesian product](https://apassionatechie.wordpress.com/2018/01/15/pandas-equivalent-of-sql-cross-join-cartesian-product/) axiom

```
data = '''id ,     type ,   flag    
1   ,    a    ,   y        
1    ,   b    ,   y
1    ,   c    ,   y
2   ,    a    ,   y      
2    ,   b    ,   y
3     ,  b     ,  y     '''
da = [[i.strip() for i in l.split(",")] for l in data.split("\n")]
df = pd.DataFrame(da[1:], columns=da[0])
# generate cartesian product https://apassionatechie.wordpress.com/2018/01/15/pandas-equivalent-of-sql-cross-join-cartesian-product/
cp = pd.DataFrame(["a","b","c"], columns=["type"])\
        .assign(foo=1)\
        .merge(pd.DataFrame(df["id"].unique(), columns=["id"]).assign(foo=1)).drop('foo',1)
df = cp.merge(df, how="outer", on=["id","type"])
df["exists"] = ~df["flag"].isnull()
df.fillna(method="ffill")
```

**output**

```
    type    id  flag    exists
0   a   1   y   True
1   a   2   y   True
2   a   3   y   False
3   b   1   y   True
4   b   2   y   True
5   b   3   y   True
6   c   1   y   True
7   c   2   y   False
8   c   3   y   False
```

Comment: Awesome. That's clever way to deal with it. I was over thinking it. Thank you :)